# Jersey Client : Using ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy

Tags: apache, jersey, jersey-client, connector

Need help in applying ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy for ApacheConnector in jersey client.

For a standalone Apache Client, we can do it this way -

```
ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {

public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
     //your strategy here..
}

};

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
.setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy)
.build();
```

But I couldn't find any way to apply strategy while using Jersey Client.
Tried registering the above feature class to WebClient but that did not help.

Any leads ?

Answer (score 0):

Jersey 2.29.1 [added support for Apache HTTP Client `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` and `ConnectionReuseStrategy`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/4202). Should work like this with `ApacheConnector`:

```
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.KEEPALIVE_STRATEGY, myStrategy);
```